# Alternative for "filtering" du command by file types only

Tags: find

The following command lists 50 largest directories (works recursively):

```
du --separate-dirs -hc  . | sort -hr | head -50
```

Performance-wise, what would be the best approach in order to **keep the same format of the output** with addition to pass an argument as an input to a function i.e. `myfunc doc docx xls xlsx ppt`. Those new 50 directories by using `myfunc` should be listed top to bottom as follows: the first directory should be the one that contains the largest **combined size** of `doc OR docx OR xls OR xlsx OR ppt` files - the rest of the file types should be completely ignored for this (opposed to displaying the total size of each directory as per `du` command).

I've noticed that `du` has `--exclude` parameter (which can't help me for this) and it seems I am looking for `--filter` parameter which doesn't exist.

```
find . \( -type f -name "*.doc" \) -o \( -type f -name "*.docx" \) -o \( -type f -name "*.xls" \)  -o \( -type f -name "*.xlsx" \)  -o \( -type f -name "*.ppt" \) -printf '%s\n' | awk '{s+=$0} END{print s+0}' | numfmt --to=iec --suffix=B --padding=7
```

Some other approaches that I've tried (as the one above) seem significantly slower than `du`.
Any ideas?

Comment: See also [Find the total size of certain files within a directory branch](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/148470) (duplicate?)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Actually, this would be almost a duplicate (within this thread I was still looking for the right approach, and within the other thread I provided some code and asked for assistance to optimize it):
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/595577/measuring-disk-usage-of-specific-file-types-per-each-directory-recursively-as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have three choices:

1. Rewrite du to filter.  Perl's File::Find might be a good starting point.
2. Write a proxy filesystem that shows only the selected files.  A fuse implementation is probably a good start.  Expect poor performance.
3. Revise an existing du implementation.

Comment: You're right. There's no quick way to resolve this. It should be implemented in `du` as a new parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small project on GitHub that recreates what I just described here. It's fully optimized by using a single output from `find` and parsing everything else inside `AWK`. Feel free to contribute:

https://github.com/madjoe/wii